# How do you display searchkit results, tables, lists, on public pages?

Tags: wordpress, profile, searchkit

Using 5.69 / Wordpress

How can you display a table created in searchkit on a public facing page on a wordpress site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change permissions on the search display and also on the form to allow anonymous access. Instructions are here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/example-membership-listing/#step-5-setting-permissions

Comment: Helpful, are you able to embed the content like you are able to embed profiles as shortcodes on WP?

Comment: Yes, there is a built-in shortcode for embedding Afforms.

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46401/how-do-you-display-searchkit-results-tables-lists-on-members-only-pages-withi